# Putting multiple values in a WHERE clause in Azure Mobile Services

Tags: c#, .net, linq, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to figure out how to put multiple values into a `WHERE` clause; this is the kind of thing you'd use a `IN` clause for in SQL.

My current code:

```
if (Log.Count() == 1)
{
    items = itemTable
        .Where(Item => Item.id == Log[0].i_id)
        .ToCollectionView();
}
else if (Log.Count() == 2)
{
    items = itemTable
        .Where(Item => Item.id == Log[0].i_id || Item.id == Log[1].i_id)
        .ToCollectionView();
}
else if (Log.Count() == 3)
{
    items = itemTable
        .Where(Item => Item.id == Log[0].i_id || Item.id == Log[1].i_id || Item.id == Log[2].i_id)
        .ToCollectionView();
}
```

It's pretty nasty. I can't find a way to put multiple values into that `WHERE` clause without a big if statement. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue. Using Any or Contains as others have suggested gave me a Not Supported Exception. I posted on the Azure Mobile Services forum and was told that IN is not supported yet. They advised I use an extension method which worked perfectly for me. Below is the code I used.

```
 public static class Extensions
{
    public async static Task<List<T>> In<T>(this IMobileServiceTable<T> table, List<int> ids)
    {
        var query = new StringBuilder("$filter=(");
        for (int i = 0; i < ids.Count; i++)
        {
            query.AppendFormat("id eq {0}", ids[i]); //don't forget to url escape and 'quote' strings
            if (i < ids.Count - 1)
            {
                query.Append(" or ");
            }
        }
        query.Append(")");
        var list = await table.ReadAsync(query.ToString());
        var items = list.Select(i => MobileServiceTableSerializer.Deserialize<T>(i)).ToList();
        return items;
    }
}
```

Your list can be populated by calling the extension method like this:

```
FavoriteJokesList = await jokeItemTable.In(favoriteJokeIds);
```

Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/azuremobile/thread/b573ff6c-1f6b-4846-b44d-4678e3d26f66

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
items = itemTable
    .Where(Item => Log.Any(logItem => logItem.i_id == Item.id))
    .ToCollectionView();
```

**Edit:** (in response to the "not supported exception")

You can try this alternative to see if the backend supports it:

```
var ids = Log.Select(logItem => logItem.i_id).ToList();
var items = itemTable
    .Where(Item => ids.Contains(Item.id))
    .ToCollectionView();
```

Comment: After some investigation, it appears to be the parameters inside the Any method that trigger it. Using `items = itemTable
    .Where(Item => Log.Any))
    .ToCollectionView();` gives no errors.

Comment: @user2070752 Right, for `IQueryable` the answer depends on what's supported by the query processor. Did the query that gives no error return the results that you expected?

Comment: The results I expected, yes. The results I need, no. It's odd, because `Log.Any(logItem => logItem.i_id == Item.id)` works as well, just not as part of `items = itemTable .Where(Item => Log.Any(logItem => logItem.i_id == Item.id)) .ToCollectionView()`.

Comment: @user2070752 See the edit to check if the other alternative is any better.

Comment: Same issue. I'm programming for WP8 in Visual Studio 2012 in C#. I dunno if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

```
items = itemTable.Where(Item => Log.Any(i => i.i_id == Item.id)).ToCollectionView();
```

Comment: by the way, it should be `i => i.i_d == ...`

Comment: @user2070752, I've tried this query under WP8 and VS2012 for a simplified sample itemTable's and Log's data and this query works fine. I haven't checked `ToCollectionView()`, so may you chech if it is the `ToCollectionView()` who throws a NotSupportedException?

Comment: Same issue using `ToListAsync()`. I'm getting my tables from Azure, so could it be a problem at their end?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, in the newest Version of the Azure Mobile Service SDK (1.0), this works:

```
var ids = Log.Select(logItem => logItem.i_id).ToList();
var items = await itemTable
.Where(Item => ids.Contains(Item.id))
.ToCollectionAsync();
```