# Azure Mobile Services 1.0: MobileServiceTableSerializer is gone, what's an alternative?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

Kind of a blend of these two questions:

[Putting multiple values in a WHERE clause in Azure Mobile Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172995/putting-multiple-values-in-a-where-clause-in-azure-mobile-services)

[Try/Catch not working for WP8 C# .NET with Azure Mobile Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232794/try-catch-not-working-for-wp8-c-sharp-net-with-azure-mobile-services)

This code:

```
public static class Extensions
{
 public async static Task<List<T>> In<T>(this IMobileServiceTable<T> table, 
 List<int> ids)
 {
    var query = new StringBuilder("$filter=(");
    for (int i = 0; i < ids.Count; i++)
    {
        query.AppendFormat("id eq {0}", ids[i]); //don't forget to url escape 
        and 'quote' strings
        if (i < ids.Count - 1)
        {
            query.Append(" or ");
        }
    }
    query.Append(")");
    var list = await table.ReadAsync(query.ToString());
    var items = list.Select(i => 
    MobileServiceTableSerializer.Deserialize<T>(i)).ToList();
    return items;
 }
}
```

no longer works with the new MobileServices 1.0, as MobileServiceTableSerializer is gone. Can anybody suggest an alternative that would do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit: found a better solution, List.Contains works now, so you can use this:

```
List<int> ids = new List() { 1, 2 };
var items = await yourTable.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id)).ToCollectionAsync();
```

Here, this works, just tested it. However there might be a better method.

And thanks for that code, might come in handy :)

```
public async static Task<List<T>> In<T>(this IMobileServiceTable<T> table,
     List<int> ids)
    {
        var query = new StringBuilder("$filter=(");
        for (int i = 0; i < ids.Count; i++)
        {
            query.AppendFormat("id eq {0}", ids[i]);
            if (i < ids.Count - 1)
            {
                query.Append(" or ");
            }
        }
        query.Append(")");
        var list = await table.ReadAsync(query.ToString());
        List<T> items = new List<T>();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            items.Add(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(item.ToString()));
        }

        return items;
    }
```